# Extending input in Haskell Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, io, parsec

I want to implement a Parsec parser for a simple language that allows file inclusions. I.e., the language looks like this:

```
include otherfile;

expression in the language;
```

If an inclusion is parsed, I want to read a file with this name and embed its parsed contents in the parent structure.

Since I have to read a file, the parser needs to be packed in IO. My guess was that the underyling monad `u` in `ParsecT s u m a` can be used for this. However, this leads to quite some changes in the language definition since the LanguageDef's rely on `Identity` as an underyling monad.

Is my approach reasonable? Are there other ways to include files within a parser, e.g., extending the input stream?

Comment: What if the `otherfile` links back to the current file such that there is an `include` loop.

Comment: The `otherfile` is in a subdirectory and cannot include the current file (the language is not a proper programming language but rather a training language). Circular references cannot occur.

Comment: Can you deal with the "include" in the tokeniser? Or else call it "#include" and pass the file through `cpp' before you parse it?

Comment: You are right, that seems to be a reasonable approach as well. I will see how complex it is to take the tokenizer apart.

Comment: Parsec et al doesn't let you dynamically alter the input stream, afaik. I see a few reasonable ways of doing this. One is to use a preprocessor (either `cpp` or a custom built one) which does a textual substitution on the input. Another is to include a case for `include` in your AST, parse the file directly and then rewrite the AST as a separate compilation pass.  A third is to build your parser on top of `IO`, load and parse the included file, and then attach the returned tree within your parser itself.

Comment: `However, this leads to many changes in the parser since all the default token parsers rely on Identity as an underyling monad.`

Judging from documentation, this is not true. For instance, all parsers from `Text.Parsec.Char` work as `ParsecT` with non-fixed `m`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson thanks a lot for this overview! I will look at these options and post my used solution.

Comment: @arrowd You are right - I meant only the default LanguageDef's, which rely on Identity. I will fix the post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what I come up with:

```
parsecTrans :: Monad m => ParsecT s u Identity a -> ParsecT s u m a
parsecTrans p = mkPT $ \s -> return $ fmap (return . runIdentity) $ runIdentity $ (runParsecT p) s
```

This function unpacks `ParsecT` monad and generalizes it to arbitrary monad. You can use it to lift all `Identity`-based parsers to `IO` based ones.

Comment: I'd probably write an instance of [`MFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.9/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) for `ParsecT s u` and write `parsecTrans = hoist generalize`